# PDO transactional code warning vs mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, pdo

So my question is about whether I should use PDO or mysqli. I'm worried about using PDO because of the following warning from the [php PDO page](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

> Warning Beware: Some MySQL table types (storage engines) do not support transactions. When writing transactional database code using a table type that does not support transactions, MySQL will pretend that a transaction was initiated successfully. In addition, any DDL queries issued will implicitly commit any pending transactions.

- What sort of problems will this cause in the future?
- Would it be better if I just used mysqli instead? (Not sure if it has the same issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the warning is because all types of mysql `storage engines` do not support transactions. The engines that do not support transactions will auto-commit the data immediately. So please check the engine list and their difference in working.

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINES;
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with databases, so if I leave the engine as the default one, it should be okay?

Comment: If you want to use transaction, then use `InnoDB`, otherwise go with the default one.